# Laravel tag all class implemeting an interface

Tags: laravel, interface, tags, bind

I'm using Laravel 8 and i want to get all the classes that implements an Interface X.

I did it with symfony4 few month ago with DI :

services.yml

```
_instanceof:
    App\Calculator\Budget\BudgetCalculatorInterface:
      tags: ['app.budget_calculator']
App\Handler\CalculatorBudgetHandler:
  arguments: [!tagged app.budget_calculator]
```

and then in my class CalculatorBudgetHandler.php

```
private $calculatorList = [];

public function __construct(iterable $calculatorList)
{
    $this->calculatorList = $calculatorList;
}

public function __construct(iterable $calculatorList)
{
    $this->calculatorList = $calculatorList;
}

public function calculate(array $data): float
{
    foreach ($this->calculatorList as $calculator) {
        if ($calculator->supports($data)) {
            return $calculator->calculate($data);
        }
    }

  
}
```

but i dot not understand how to do it with Laravel. I think i have to pass all my classes in a bind or tag :

```
$this->app->tag([CpuReport::class, MemoryReport::class], 'reports');
```

thats mean if i got a new class implementing X, i have to add it in the bind/tag ?
I want to do it automatically .

thx !

Comment: You have to [bind](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding) the interface, it is really simple ! Check out the documentation...

Comment: @matiaslauriti already read it, but still don't figure out how i'll get all my classes ?

Comment: sorry, what part don't you understand ? can you update your question with an example ? If you say "still can't figure out how I'll get **all** my classes", you lost me there, explain more.

Comment: @matiaslauriti i updated my example with symfony.
let assume you have 3 classes : A,B,C all implementing an interface X.
i want to get all the classes implementing X in an iterable/array to foreach on thoses classes, in a handler, a command or whatever.
and if i create a new class D, implementing X i dont, want to have to add a new line like 
$this->app->bind(InterfaceX::class, ClassD::class);

Basicly in my symfony example, all my classes implementing an interface are tagged, and with DI i send all those tagged classes to a Handler

Comment: I am still confused, sorry. Are you saying that you don't want to do `$this->app->bind(InterfaceX::class, ClassA::class);` and then `ClassB`, `ClassC`, and if you have a new one like `ClassD` also do not do that again ? If you answer is yes, you can't do even more than 1, if you do more than 1 `bind` you are replacing the class. The idea of the `interface` is to always return the same class for that interface. I think you can specify that in `X` controller, you want a `ClassA`, but on `Y` controller you want `ClassB` (using interfaces), but that is not normal on Laravel.

Comment: You can do `public function __construct(ClassA $class)` and on the other controller or class `public function __construct(ClassB $class)` and it will be automatically injected by Laravel.

Comment: what you did on Symfony makes no sense, why would you need an interface but have to define what it needs (different classes on each controller) ? It makes sense to have each class implement the interface, but when you go to each controller, define explicitly what you need, as that controller is unique for a route, it is not "multi purpose" (that is why makes no sense).

Comment: As you maybe now, if you require a `Model` for each route, you are not requiring an interface of it (it doesn't matter if it exists or not), you are explicitly requiring the model you need. Do same with your example. The idea of `binding` an interface is to require the interface wherever you need the only associated class.

Comment: @matiaslauriti let see that another way, without interfaces.

i got to ship products. i got a class per carrier (ups, fedex...)
to choose my carrier i got a property (or many properties) to check in an Product model.

i want to avoid in my handler a big switch or if like this :
if ($productModl->property == ''foo") {$carrier = new UpsCarrier();} elseif() ...

so i like to find a way  to loop on all my carrier classes, like my example in symfony. for that i need a way to inject all those classes in my constructor, or whatever the way to get them.

Comment: @matiaslauritii did not understand your comment on my symfony code ? i do not use that in a controller.

Comment: Okay, let me ask again: Where are you trying to use this code ? I see `CalculatorBudgetHandler` class. Where is that class used ? Can you give me more info ? Is it used in a controller ? What are you passing to this handler class ? I think your fix would be to understand the pattern you are using and maybe do it Laravel way with the pattern or change it to another one that will get better along with Laravel.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now. So you want to have an array of classes to be iterated over, but those clases implement the same interface, so if you need `InterfaceX` you want to get all classes that implement that interface, right ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes basicly. but the interface may not be the better way to do so.
i just need a way to get all my Carrier Classes, and if create a new one (PostCanadaCarrier.php or whatever) it has to be automatically  in the classes array. If that's possible.

Comment: You can achieve something like that, but is more complex, you can [follow this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding-typed-variadics) and when you require the iterable, return an array of the desired classes, but I am not 100% sure it will work. Never done so !

Answer (score 5):

I needed this too. Looked for a longer time and I basically found a solution. The bad thing about this is that in PHP classes aren't actually declared when you did not `use` them. So you'll have to either scan the entire project for classes and test each class to find classes implementing your interface or (better) you use the composer autoload class maps. There you could probably limit the searching scope for classes to a sub namespace.

A small but cool package working this way is this one: https://gitlab.com/hpierce1102/ClassFinder - basically it uses composer PSR4 classmaps and is in general fine performance wise.

Here is the solution to which I came:

```php
// Add to service provider
private function tagByInterface(string $interfaceName, string $tagName, string $rootNamespace)
{
    foreach (ClassFinder::getClassesInNamespace($rootNamespace, ClassFinder::RECURSIVE_MODE) as $className) {
        $class = new \ReflectionClass($className);
        if ($class->isAbstract() || $class->isInterface()) {
            continue;
        }

        if ($class->implementsInterface($interfaceName)) {
            $this->app->tag($className, $tagName);
        }
    }
}
```

Which can then be used like this in the `register()`:

```php
$this->tagByInterface(SomeInterface::class, 'some-tag', 'App\Domain\Something');

$this->app->when(SomeClass::class)->needs('$myServices')->giveTagged('some-tag');
```

As the classes are loaded using reflection, this operation still might take time if your root namespace is not properly set or too wide. Reflection is quick (as far as I know quicker than loading the information from cache), but you should still think of using a deferred provider for the task so that the search for implementing classes only triggers when it's actually needed.

### Update some months later

This solution works, but might be a huge drain on performance if the project gets big. I'm now caching the tagged classes. Something like this:

```php
use HaydenPierce\ClassFinder\ClassFinder as HPClassFinder;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository;

class InheritanceClassFinder
{
    public function __construct(private ?Repository $cache = null)
    {
    }

    public function findClassesImplementingOrExtending(string $interfaceOrClass, string $rootNamespace): array
    {
        if ($this->cache) {
            return $this->cache->rememberForever(
                'inheriting-classes-'.$interfaceOrClass,
                fn () => $this->findClassesInheriting($interfaceOrClass, $rootNamespace));
        }

        return $this->findClassesInheriting($interfaceOrClass, $rootNamespace);
    }

    private function findClassesInheriting(string $interfaceOrClass, string $rootNamespace): array
    {
        $classes = [];
        foreach (HPClassFinder::getClassesInNamespace($rootNamespace, HPClassFinder::RECURSIVE_MODE) as $className) {
            if (!is_subclass_of($className, $interfaceOrClass)
                || ($class = new \ReflectionClass($className))->isAbstract() || $class->isInterface()) {
                continue;
            }

            $classes[] = $className;
        }

        return $classes;
    }
}
```

This means as long as the cache is injected, stuff will be loaded once and then taken from cache. I inject the cache only in production, so locally its a bit slower but always up to date. In production I throw away the cache with every deployment, so I get a fresh load once after every deployment.